# Position an image exactly next to the text

Tags: html, css, position

I have a small text:

```
"This is a giraffe:"
```

I want, exactly to its right (very close to the text, NOT with img's float:right, because it sends the image way to the right), to position a small giraffe image.

How is this possible?

EDIT

So, I was asked to provide some context.

So, what I've tried:

```
<p>This is a giraffe: <img src="giraffe.png" style="float:right" /> </p>
```

Comment: What HTML/CSS have you tried? This seems very trivial so it's hard to tell where you're having an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your current code it's difficult to tell but you could do something like this:

```
<span>This is a giraffe:</span><img src="..." />
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qytHJ/

`span` and `img` elements are both **inline** so they will flow right next to each other by default.

Comment: Weird, I thought that using it this way would place the image below the text, for some reason...

Comment: +1 for the simple solution. Sometimes SO is just full of idiots who downvotes without checking for validity, or adding anything meaningful to the discussion.

Comment: @Terry Thanks, yeah I figured as much, but for a second there I thought I was in the wrong! Hahaha